# How can I handle an incoming packet connection by parsing the buffer and placing the data into the correct struct?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, buffer, recv

I have an open connection that works fine, but now I'm adding a second reply type that I have to handle.  The replies go to two different structs.

Reply type one is a struct of size 16 = replyTypeOne (int, int, int, int)
Reply type two is a struct of size 64 = replyTypeTwo (int, int, int, char[48], int)

Before I was sending the reply straight to the correct struct - now I have to add a buffer to determine which struct the reply should go to.

old handle of code below:

```
iResult = recv(connectSocket, (char *)&replyTypeOne, sizeof(replyTypeOne), 0);
```

The above code would place the reply fields into their appropiate places.  However, with the replyTypeTwo being different than replyTypeOne - I need a solution to determine the two replies from each other.

So I plan on using a buffer (maybe I should use MSG_PEEK??), to look at the incoming data and place it into the correct struct.  I'm just not sure how to handle / parse the buffer reply atm.

EDIT:
added replyTemp struct -  int, int, int, int, char[48], int

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 128

int iResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

iResult = recv(connectSocket, (char *)&replyTemp, sizeof(replyTemp), 0)

if(iResult > 0)
{
 if(replyTemp.length > 16)
  {
   //handle replyTypeTwo -  assign replyTypeTwo fields to replyTemp fields
  } else {
   // handle replyTypeOne - asking replyTypeOne fields to replyTemp fields
  }
}
else if(iResult == 0)
{
  connectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

Comment: Unless there’s some in-band way of distinguishing a valid `replyTypeOne` from the first 16 bytes of a valid `replyTypeTwo`, or some out-of-band information telling you which one you should be expecting to receive, you need to add some kind of framing protocol that carries that information for each message. Otherwise you’re just asking for magic.

Comment: Well the first int is the length the reply packet.  I only receive two different packets and they both have different lengths.  Wouldn't this establish the difference?

Comment: Since both packets are quite small and the length is the first field, why not read in the entire packet first and then use the length to populate the correct struct?

Comment: Wouldn't the length be equal to the buffer length?  I guess I'm confused on how to parse the buffer to check the packet length.  Right now I have everything going into a TempStruct and once I look at replyTemp.length I copy the data into the correct struct.

Comment: You need to update your question to explain the necessary information. Otherwise, nobody is going to see it but the two or three people who are already looking into your question; the hundreds of others who could potentially help you will mostly just see an incomplete question and move on (possibly downvoting or close voting).

Comment: What needs to be updated?  I think it's explained

Comment: @user3622460 There's nothing at all in the question that says that the length is in the first `int` field for both structs. If there were, Jonathan Potter wouldn't have written an answer that suggests doing effectively the same thing you're already doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to “peek” is to just `recv` and then `recv` some more.

Since this appears to be TCP, you already need a `recv` loop. A `recv` loop is always necessary with TCP. When you ask to `recv(sock, &buf, 16, 0)`, there's no guarantee you'll get 16 bytes. If the message got split across two packets at the sender, you could get only, say, the 10 bytes in the first packet, and not get the 6 bytes from the next packet until you do a second `recv`. So, you need to keep receiving until you get all 16 bytes. (I've written [a longer explanation in Python terms](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html), but the same idea applies to C++.)

Once you're doing that, all we have to do after getting 16 bytes is check the length field (which you implied is the first 4 bytes in both structs). If it's 16, we're done; if not, we can just keep looping until we have 64 bytes.

Ideally we want to read into a single buffer of 64 bytes, instead of reading a 16-byte buffer and a 48-byte buffer and then memmoving stuff around to concatenate them. Given that, we can just use a `union` to allow us to `recv` into a 64-byte char array, but then access the first 16 bytes as a `reply_type_1` or the whole thing as a `reply_type_2`.

So, here’s a quick and dirty example (without handling errors, EOF, etc.):

```
typeset union {
    reply_type_1 r1;
    reply_type_2 r2;
    char buf[64];
} msg_type;

int len = 0;
msg_type msg;
while (len < sizeof(reply_type_1)) {
    n = recv(sock, &msg.buf[len], sizeof(reply_type_1)-len, 0);
    len += n;
}
if msg.r1.length > sizeof(reply_type_1) {
    while (len < sizeof(reply_type_2)) {
        n = recv(sock, &msg.buf[len], sizeof(reply_type_2)-len, 0);
        len += n;
    }
    do_stuff_r2(msg.r2);
} else {
    do_stuff_r1(msg.r1);
}
```

Storing into `msg.buf` and then accessing `msg.r1` is effectively the same thing as just having a `char buf[64]` and then doing `do_stuff_r1(*reinterpret_cast<reply_type_1 *>(&buf))`. So, if `do_stuff_r1` takes a `reply_type_1`, it gets a copy of the first 16 bytes as a `reply_type_1` struct, and if it takes a `reply_type_1 &`, it gets a reference to the first 16 bytes as a `reply_type_1` struct.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this.  Above my socket is open and I'm inside of a while loop where data is constantly streaming in.  At the do_stuff_r2 -  that function is taking in the message buffer -  how is it parsing the data from the message the buffer?

Comment: I'm guessing memcpy(r2.length, buf, 4)  - all the way down to the size

Comment: @user3622460 I'm not sure what part you don't understand. Do you not know how `union` works?

Comment: A union will use the larger struct - but I still have to parse the data or is the data automatically parsing into the struct?   The do_stuff_r2() function calls are confusing me

Comment: @user3622460 I've updated the answer to explain more. If there's something you still don't get, let me know.

Comment: Yes makes sense -  tested it and it works  - ty you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use a common header that all the reply packets inherit from, with a type (and often a size) field in it. Then all you have to do is check the type and cast appropriately.

You'll need to enhance the code to deal with the case when you receive an incomplete packet (or more than one packet at once), but the basics of this would be:

```
struct replyCommon
{
    short type;
};

struct replyOne : public replyCommon
{
    int a, b, c, d;
};

struct replyTwo : public replyCommon
{
    int a, b, c;
    char d[48];
    int e;
};

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 128

int iResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

iResult = recv(connectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)

if(iResult > sizeof(replyCommon))
{
    if (reinterpret_cast<replyCommon*>(recvbuf)->type == 1)
        handleReplyOne(reinterpret_cast<replyOne*>(recvbuf));
    else
    if (reinterpret_cast<replyCommon*>(recvbuf)->type == 2)
        handleReplyTwo(reinterpret_cast<replyTwo*>(recvbuf));

}
else if(iResult == 0)
{
  connectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

Comment: How does it know type 1 from type 2?

Comment: Is their no way to just peak at the first two reply ints (in my case the Length and ID) which would tell me what type of struct is needed.  From here couldn't I just use iResult = recv(connectSocket, (char *)&replyTypeOne, sizeof(replyTypeOne), 0);